# do i need to reference the invite id of the user in discord to make a command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a problem making a discord bot, my bot is working and everything is fine, and I have the following rules, the user enters the server and he can use the command 5 times, and then when he invites someone and the person enters the server it receives 5 more commands, and it is specific for each user and invitation, is this possible to do? follow my code. In my case with this code, the user already starts without being able to use the command and when he uses the command/invitation he already gets 5 commands to use even if the person has not yet entered the server.

the invitation command really works, but the bug is that when the user uses /convidar he already gets the other 5 commands even if the person has not joined the server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
channel = bot.get_channel(1098287308052107465)

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

invite_uses = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")

@bot.command()
async def convidar(ctx):
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite(reason=None, max_age=0, max_uses=0, temporary=False, unique=True)
    await ctx.send(f"Aqui está o convite para o servidor: {invite.url}")
    inviter_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    invite_uses[inviter_id] = invite_uses.get(inviter_id, 0) + 5

@bot.command()
async def texto(ctx, *, message):
    inviter_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if inviter_id in invite_uses and invite_uses[inviter_id] > 0:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Busca por texto",
            description=message[::-1],
            color=discord.Color.blue()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        invite_uses[inviter_id] -= 1
    else:
        await ctx.send("Você atingiu o limite de usos. Convide mais pessoas para ganhar mais usos.")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.bot:  # Ignore bot joins
        return
    inviter_id = str(member.inviter.id)
    invite_uses[inviter_id] = invite_uses.get(inviter_id, 0) + 5
    print(f"{member.name} joined the server. Invite uses reset to {invite_uses[inviter_id]} for the inviter.")

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).